# Is Harvey Bullock in the Chris Nolan Batman movies?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy

I remember in the Batman animated series there was a character, [Harvey Bullock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Bullock_%28comics%29), that was always against Batman and was the big blubbering stereotypical cop.

Is he portrayed in the newest Batman movies? I thought it might have been the corrupt cop played by [Mark Boone Junior](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0095478/), but his character's name was Flass.

Was there any other reference to Harvey Bullock?

Comment: Is a new [tag:chris-nolan] tag necessary, given the question isn't about his overall work nor about him specifically?  It's just about his Batman work, which is covered by [tag:batman] and we already have tags for all of his Batman movies if you want to reference each individually.

Comment: I wanted to distinquish between other batman movies and Chris Nolan's batman movies. And since he's now starting to do other superhero works, I think it is necessary for the distinction.

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2085/1109

Comment: It might be worth noting that Flass was a corrupt detective in Batman: Year One, which was a huge inspiration for the Chris Nolan Films: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Arnold_Flass_(New_Earth)

Comment: I never read Batman Year One, so I never made that connection.

Comment: On a side (and late) note, I'm pretty sure the TAS character of Bullock was inspired by Lieutenant Eckhardt in the 1989 film. After all, the cartoon was largely based on the '89 film and its sequel, and about the only difference between the two characters is that one was dirty and the other wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**While Harvey Bullock did make the rounds of various DC properties including:**

- The DC Animated Universe - Harvey Bullock is portrayed by Robert Costanzo
- DC Universe Online - Harvey Bullock is portrayed by Edwin Neal
- Batman: Knightfall for BBC Radio 1 Bullock was voiced by Eric Meyers.

Harvey Bullock did not make the cut in the Dark Knight Rises. There were rumors that Tom Hardy would be cast as Harvey Bullock in The Dark Knight Rises but the rumors were unsubstantiated. He instead ends up cast as Bane.

**Rumors sites included:**

- **Movie Web:** [The Dark Knight Rises Has Tom Hardy as Detective Harvey Bullock?](http://www.movieweb.com/news/the-dark-knight-rises-has-tom-hardy-as-detective-harvey-bullock)
- **Cinema Blend.com:** [Could Tom Hardy Play Detective Harvey Bullock in The Dark Knight Rises?](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Could-Tom-Hardy-Play-Det-Harvey-Bullock-In-The-Dark-Knight-Rises-21438.html)
- **Total Film:** [Tom Hardy as Harvey Bullock in the Dark Knight Rises?](http://www.totalfilm.com/news/tom-hardy-as-harvey-bullock-in-the-dark-knight-rises)

[image: Tom Hardy as Bane]

*Tom Hardy as Bane*

Comment: Do you have references to the rumors you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

No. Harvey Bullock was not realized in live action until September 22, 2014, where he appeared in *Gotham* and was portrayed as James 'Jim' Gordon's (played by actor Ben McKenzie) partner he was played by Donal Logue.